# React with Okta - LoginCallback called twice

Tags: reactjs, okta

I managed to integrate my react app with Okta authentication and it works. However, I'm facing the following problem:

1. I enter my app > Okta-hosted login screen appears > I press "Login" with credentials
2. LoginCallback component is called and therefore delivers me to the initial screen.
3. I can see the initial screen for a brief moment and then I see on the URL bar that the callback is called again, delivering me again on the same screen.

My question is, why is the LoginCallback component called twice? I don't have any control over it, as it is imported from React.

This is an MVP that demonstrates the issue:

`App.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Security, LoginCallback } from "@okta/okta-react";
import { oktaConfig } from "./oktaConfig";
import { OktaAuth, toRelativeUrl } from "@okta/okta-auth-js";

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);
const logout = async () => {
  const basename = window.location.origin + "/";
  await oktaAuth.signOut({ postLogoutRedirectUri: basename });
};
const Home = () => (
  <div>
    Home Page (Public)
    <button onClick={logout}>logout</button>
  </div>
);
const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const restoreOriginalUri = async (_oktaAuth, originalUri) => {
    navigate(toRelativeUrl(originalUri || "/", window.location.origin));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe to authentication state changes
    oktaAuth.authStateManager.subscribe((authState) => {
      if (!authState.isAuthenticated && !authState.isPending) {
        console.log("User is not authenticated");
        oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login/callback" element={<LoginCallback />} />
      </Routes>
    </Security>
  );
};
export default App;
```